# Connect to android emulator with C#

Tags: c#, android-emulator

I have an .apk package that i want to push it into android emulator and run in emulator and then receive events and debug message to show to user with C# console program.
How should i connect to android emulator for receiving debug message from C# code console?
please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how much detail you want. Do you simply want to view the logcat or get full debug info(like breakpoints and device statistics)?

In the case of the former:

You can use the adb(Android Debug Bridge):

```
ProcessStartInfo adbStart = new ProcessStartInfo(@"your_path\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe", "-e logcat *:D");
adbStart.UseShellExecute = false;
Process adb = new Process() { StartInfo = adbStart };
adb.Start();
```

Replace the first parameter in the constructor of `adbStart` with the path to your adb.exe, found in the `platform_tools` folder of your Android SDK. The second parameter is console flags. The above code forces the adb to only connect to an emulator using the `-e` flag and filters to debug messages only using the `*:D` flag. You should replace the `*` with a relevant filter for your app(like a package name). Just type `adb help` in a console for info on the different flags.

Since your program runs in the console, the standard output of the adb SHOULD be directed to your console. If it isn't, use the `StreamReader` at `adb.StandardOutput` to read the output of the adb. You can use `adb.WaitForExit()` to block the thread until adb dies.

In the case of the latter:

The official way to do this is via the Dalvik Debug Monitor(android_sdk\tools\ddms.bat). Since there is no official support for C# in android, the debug monitor is written in Java and so are the libs. I can't find any substitutes, sorry. Java is very similar to C# though, maybe you can jump languages for this particular project?

Comment: I apologize that I did not explain my problem more. I already create windows form C# program that developer could develop android application program. My partners write an engine with java that i add new module with C# program to it's package and rebuild with apktool and resign package with jar signer. next problem for me is how can i push my apk to android emulator for run and debug?

Comment: Get the path to your apk file. Then use the method above to execute the adb, but replace the second parameter in the first constructor with "install {pathToYourApk}". That should push and install the app to your device with minimal user interaction. To run an app, do the method again but this time with "shell am start -n com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity" (of course you should use your app's package name and main activity)

Comment: `shell am start -e debug true -n com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity` <- better flags. There is a nice article on debugging [here](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/using-jdb-with-adb-to-debugging-of-android-app-on-a-real-device/)