# Embed mobile emulator in Windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, android-emulator

Dears

I am creating a windows forms application (c#) in which allows the user to upload .apk file to number of participants and hence my program will analyse some UAT properties.

My question is: is it possible to show any emulator inside a winform application and is it possible to communicate with it? In other words, is there any APIs or extensions for Android Emulator that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to say no.  This is a very complicated idea, and probably not something that you should be attempting as it could take many months/years to achieve.  However, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126409/connect-to-android-emulator-with-c-sharp